# Let $K$ a field, $x_1,...,x_n\in K$ $x_i\neq 0$ for all $i$ and $a_1,...,a_n\in K$ not all zero. Prove that $a_1x_1^s+...+a_nx_n^s\neq 0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Here is the complete question:

> Let $K$ a field, $x_1,...,x_n\in K$ with $x_i\neq 0$ for all $i$ and $x_i\neq x_j$ if $i\neq j$, $a_1,...,a_n\in K$ not all zero and $S\neq \langle 0\rangle$ a semisubgroup of additive group $\mathbb{Z}$. Prove that exists $s\in S$ such that $a_1x_1^s+...+a_nx_n^s\neq 0$.

This is a question off cyclic extension section in my book. I don't know how start the question, if someone had hint.

Comment: This seems to need some extra assumptions, taking $K=\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $x_1=x_2=a_1=a_2=1$, we have $1\cdot 1^s+1\cdot 1^s=0$ for all $s \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You're right, i forgot the fact that $x_i\neq x_j$ if $i\neq j$. I will edit, thanks.

Comment: Nice question,  Have you tried multinomial theorem? I am assume Char(K) is finite non zero. I will work on this at night. Very Nice Question. K is finite or Infinite in your question,?

Comment: Is $x_{i}$ are all elements of K.or there are other elements in K too

Comment: @SafalDasBiswas I don't try this theorem. Don't have more assumption on $K$, so he can be finite or infinite. And i think we can assume char(K) is finite non zero, the chapter is almost all that way, although the question don't say nothing about the char(K). We can have other elements in $K$ too, not only the $x_i$.

Comment: Sir, I will definately think this question,  as it's very interesting. I followed this question to answer my idea latter.

Comment: Your specification of $S$ is weird and wrong (what if $S = \{ kn, k\ge 0\}$ and the $x_i$ are the $n$-th roots of unity and $\sum_j a_j = 0$ ?). If you meant $S = \Bbb{N}$ then see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix